# I'm having problems with my code, cause i can't fix the code without cstring

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>

int main ( void )
{
    int computerGuess;
    int count =1;
    int low = 1;
    int high = 100;

    char resposta[5];
    char res[1];
    count = 0;

    printf ("Computer, enter a number, 1 - 100: ");

    computerGuess = (rand() %100)+1; // nao pode ser 0 nem 100
    printf("%d\n",computerGuess);

    while ( 1 )
    {
        while (1) {
            printf("\nResposta do utilizador (HIGH, LOW ou OK): ");
            scanf("%s", &resposta);

            if (strcmp("HIGH",resposta) == 0) {
                high = computerGuess;

                break;
            }
            else if (strcmp("LOW",resposta ) == 0) {
                low = computerGuess;
                break;
            }
            else if(strcmp("OK",resposta) == 0) {
                printf("Eu, o computador poderoso Ganhou!");
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            }
            else {
                printf("Resposta Invalida. Tenta de novo:");
            }
        }
        printf("high: %d || low: %d\n", high,low);

        if(low +1== high || low == high) {
            printf("\nVou cancelar o jogo. O utilizador enganou-se, ou trocou o numero.");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if(low==99)
            ++low;

        computerGuess = ( high + low ) / 2;

        printf ( "Guess #%d: % 3d ", ++count, computerGuess );
    }
}
```

I tried cstring on C, but is not working. How can i fix the code without cstring and strcmp. Ignore things inside printf, cause is a work that i'm doing in PT.

The goal of the program is: The computer says a number, and I say high, low, ..., so that at some point it will guess the number I thought of in my head. But the computer can only have 7 tries.

Answer (score 1):

`<cstring>` is a C++ thing. In C just `#include <string.h>`.

C and C++ are two **different** languages, don't mix them.

Comment: I changed that and now is working BUT: The computer is saying like 92, and i said LOW and the computer keeps saying numbers above 92.

Comment: That is when you take a debugger and step through the program until you understand what is wrong.